# HttpClient 4.3.4 Get request returning login page

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using selenium to login to a website and when it has been logged in to I execute some tasks. After executing these tasks I have to download and verify the contents of a PDF document. Since selenium doesn't support downloading documents I decided to use Apache HttpClient 4.3.4.

I found [this](http://jsystem.org/downloading-files-using-selenium-and-apache-httpclient/) website which pretty much covered all the points I thought were required for the GET request. After I implemented this code and changed it to work for HttpClient 4.3.4 and my website, I ended up with the following code:

```
public void dowloadFile(String dowloadURL, String outputFileLocation, String outputFileName) throws Exception {
    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy(){
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        });
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            builder.build());

    CookieStore cookieStore = seleniumCookiesToCookieStore();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(baseURL + dowloadURL);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                File directoriesFile = new File(outputFileLocation);
                directoriesFile.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(outputFileLocation + "\\" + outputFileName);
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
                log.info("Downloaded " + outputFile.length() + " bytes. " + entity.getContentType());
            }
            else {
                log.warn("Download failed!");
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
}

private CookieStore seleniumCookiesToCookieStore() {
    Set<Cookie> seleniumCookies = this.driver.manage().getCookies();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    for(Cookie seleniumCookie : seleniumCookies){
        BasicClientCookie basicClientCookie =
            new BasicClientCookie(seleniumCookie.getName(), seleniumCookie.getValue());
        basicClientCookie.setDomain(seleniumCookie.getDomain());
        basicClientCookie.setExpiryDate(seleniumCookie.getExpiry());
        basicClientCookie.setPath(seleniumCookie.getPath());
        cookieStore.addCookie(basicClientCookie);
    }
    return cookieStore;
}
```

After executing this code the file produced was a file containing the html for the login page of the website. Looking at the cookies there is one cookie called `PD-S-SESSION-ID` on the login screen and when I have logged in there is still the `PD-S-SESSION-ID` cookie but with a different value and a new cookie named `JSESSIONID`. What I am wondering is if there something I have overlooked or something wrong with my code itself?